# prevent hard coded numbers in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

How may I prevent hard coded numbers in C++?

For example if I have `Score+=10;`
In C I would do:

```
#define FACTOR 10
Score+=FACTOR
```

But In C++ my professor told we don't use `#define` anymore (It's a C thing and risky), So what should I use?

Comment: When applicable you can use `enum`, but I see nothing wrong with `#define` in that particular example.

Comment: I prefer `static const unsigned int FACTOR = 10u;` but YMMV.

Comment: In C++17, `inline constexpr auto factor = 10;`.

Comment: @Havenard can the value of enum change in runtime?

Comment: By the way I think the appropriate term here is "magic number" not "hard coded number". You will always have hard coded numbers, what you're trying to avoid are those kind of numbers that only the programmer knows why they're there because numbers aren't self-documented, like variables are if you give them adequate names. So we replace those magic numbers for names that express what those numbers mean.

Comment: No, enums are sets of values that only have meaning at compile time, just like `#define` except `#define` is handled by the preprocessor.

Comment: @Havenard, `enum` is inappropriate here, when you have a single constant. Are you seriously suggesting something equivalent to `enum MyFactorEnum { FACTOR=10}` ? Josh, the value of a variable of some enumerated type can certainly change at runtime.

Comment: @Havenard: But I agree with you that `#define` is perfectly fine here. Josh, I would suggest that you make the name more specific than `FACTOR`, to guard against accidental name clashes.

Comment: Go get a new professor. There is nothing wrong with `#define`. While you can use `const type` in C++ (or a global `enum`), there is 30 years of code out there that uses `#define` and it is not a deprecated feature of either C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` or `const int`, but I see nothing wrong with #define in that particular example and I prefer to use #define

Answer (score 0):

I hope your professor is allowing you to use C++17/20 or at least C++11.
If that's the case, you best use constexpr for every constant.

```
constexpr auto FACTOR = 10;
```

From C++17 on, you can even use this to create classes as constants within class/struct scope without ODR violations.

```
 struct S
 {
     constexpr static std::string_view STR = "str"sv;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Doesn't belong to  namespaces, and cannot be kept in namespaces.
macro named "max" (as windows.h does), and you try to use std::max(a,b), then at least some compilers will still do macro substitution, giving something like std::(a<b?b:a),
2.Debugging is Difficult in #define since it is a pre processor runs before the execution of code.